# HTML::style() in laravel, encodes html special characters

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use `{{ HTML::style('css/bootsrap-theme-min.css') }}` to render my CSS links, but instead of normal HTML, i get it encoded to html entities, like so:

```
&lt;link media=&quot;all&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot;        rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;http://localhost:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css&quot;&gt;
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5 or 5.1 use

```
{!! HTML::style('css/bootsrap-theme-min.css') !!}
```

For Laravel 4

```
{{{ HTML::style('css/bootsrap-theme-min.css') }}}
```

By default Laravel escapes the variables that you enclose with `{{ ... }}`, `{!! ... !!}` or `{{{ ... }}}` tags tells Laravel not to.

Answer (score 1):

You can add version too

```
{!! HTML::style('css/bootsrap-theme-min.css?v='.$version) !!}
```